# Android stop Child activity from parent Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a base activity that does some authentication checks like follows:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected MyApp application;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        application = (MyApp) getApplication();

        if (application.getAuth() == null || !application.getAuth().isLoggedIn()) {

            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }

    }        
}
```

When the above BaseActivity finds that Auth is null, i redirect the user to the login Activity and call finish and return. The problem is that the activity that is inherits from it still runs it's onCreate code.

How can i stop the Activity inheriting from the BaseActivity to run at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep one member variable in your base activity. Something like:
`protected boolean authFailed = false`. Before returning from base activity, you can make `authFailed  = true`.
In your child class, after caliing super.onCreate, you can check the value of this protected variable. And can return from child activity if its `true`.